# WCF Data service how to query navigation property that a collection

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-data-services

I have a project I am working on that has a Order entity that has a navigation property for OrderITems:

```
public class Order
{
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }

   public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to be able to query the Orders with a filter against the collection of OrderItems

ex:
http:\mysvc.com\mysvc\Orders?$filter=OrderItems\ProductId eq 1234

However, I cannot seem to get this to work. Any ideas? I'd be happy to provide more details.

Project is using an EntityFramework code first 4.1 data provider.

Updated with exception and callstack:

```
Not Implemented Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Data.Services.Internal.ProjectedWrapper1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.System.NotSupportedException   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, ConstantExpression linq)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConditionalTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, ConditionalExpression linq)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()

   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)

   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)

   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()

   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()

   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()

   at System.Data.Services.Internal.ProjectedWrapper.EnumerableWrapper.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()

   at System.Data.Services.WebUtil.GetRequestEnumerator(IEnumerable enumerable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the currently released bits you would have to turn the query around:

/OrderItems?$expand=Order&$filter=ProductId eq 1234

The downside to this approach is that if a single order has two OrderItems with the filtered product ID you will get the same order twice. Also you will get all the filtered OrderItems. You might use $select to scope down the amount of data downloaded.

In the latest CTP (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/13/announcing-wcf-data-services-oct-2011-ctp-for-net-4-and-silverlight-4.aspx) there's a support for any/all, which is what you would use here. See this blog post for details http://www.odata.org/blog/even-more-any-and-all.

Comment: Thanks Vitek. That is what I was hoping to avoid. As this is a project going to production in less than a month I don't believe I could use the new CTP but this looks good for the future. On another note. Unfortunately, my $select fails with a 'Not Implemented' error.

Comment: Re 'Not Implemented': This probably means you're using some kind of custom provider on the server. So you would need to contact whoever wrote that server provider about this.

Comment: Actually, I created the provider and it is a pretty standard EF Code First 4.1 provider.

Comment: I am however using some custom URL rewriting to achieve the clean, restful uri. Could that be the issue?

Comment: In that case, can you post the full exception including the callstack?

Comment: This is all I get in response. The debugger is set to stop on any exception and does not catch anything.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">Not Implemented</message>
</error>

Comment: Try setting config.UseVerboseErrors = true in your InitializeService.

Comment: Wow! That was quite different. Updated OP.

Comment: Hmm - what is the exact URL you're sending to the server? It must have some $select in it, right? If possible, could you please send the repro project to me: vitek . karas at microsoft dot com

Comment: Thanks Vitek. I have sent the project to you.

Comment: This now fixed per your suggestions in the related post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946875/wcf-data-service-select-returning-not-implemented-exception